# Is "best-possible obfuscation" really what its name indicates?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, obfuscation

The paper [On Best-Possible Obfuscation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.4265&rep=rep1&type=pdf) defines what is calls "best-possible obfuscation",

and proves (propositions 3.4 and 3.5) that efficient best-possible

obfuscators are exactly efficient [indistinguishability obfuscators](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/451.pdf).

However, it is not clear to me that their definition corresponds to their name.

Inspired by the paper [On the (Im)possibility of Obfuscation](http://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390001.pdf) (though obviously not

using that paper's definition), I define the "better obfuscator hypothesis" as follows:

> There exists a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $\operatorname{Obf}$ such that,
>   
>   with all probabilities involving $\operatorname{Obf}$ implicitly taken over $\operatorname{Obf}$'s randomness in
>   
>   addition to what is indicated explicitly in the subscript, one has the following:
>   
>   $\;$ for all circuits $C$, $\;\; \operatorname{Prob}\left(\operatorname{Obf}(C\hspace{.03 in}) \text{ is a circuit that computes the same function as } C\right) \: = \: 1$
>   
> and
>    $\;$ for all families of polynomial-size circuits $\mathcal{F}\hspace{-0.02 in}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}\hspace{-0.03 in}_1$, if
>   
>    $\;$ $\;$ for all adversaries $\mathcal{B}$ that are restricted to polynomially-many
>   
>    $\;$ $\;$ oracle queries but are (otherwise) computationally unbounded,
>   
>    $\;$ $\;$ $\left|\hspace{.02 in}\operatorname{Prob}_{C\leftarrow \mathcal{F}_0}\hspace{-0.05 in}\left(\mathcal{B}^C\hspace{-0.03 in}(\operatorname{size}(C\hspace{.03 in})) = 1\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)-\operatorname{Prob}_{C\leftarrow \mathcal{F}_1}\hspace{-0.05 in}\left(\mathcal{B}^C\hspace{-0.03 in}(\operatorname{size}(C\hspace{.03 in})) = 1\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)\right| \;$ is negligible
>   
>  $\;$ then
>    $\;$ $\;$  for all feasible adversaries $\mathcal{A}$,
>   
>    $\;$ $\;$ $\left|\operatorname{Prob}_{C\leftarrow \mathcal{F}_0}\hspace{-0.05 in}(\mathcal{A}(\operatorname{Obf}(C\hspace{.03 in})) = 1)-\operatorname{Prob}_{C\leftarrow \mathcal{F}_1}\hspace{-0.05 in}(\mathcal{A}(\operatorname{Obf}(C\hspace{.03 in})) = 1)\right| \;$ is negligible
>   
>   .

(With respect to non-uniform adversaries, indistinguishability obfuscation

is equivalent to replacing "families" with "sequences" in that definition.)

**Questions:**
Is the "better obfuscator hypothesis" known to be false?

Is the "better obfuscator hypothesis" known to be equivalent to the existence

of an efficient best-possible obfuscator, as defined on [page 7 of paper #1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.4265&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=8)?

Comment: Another confusion I have is how how you pick a circuit $C$ from a family $\mathcal{F}_i$? Since you say "families of polynomial size circuits", then the family must be infinite, so how do you pick a random circuit? Do you fix the size and the statements must hold for every size?

Comment: I use [distribution ensembles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_ensemble). $\:$ (I suppose I could edit that fact into the question.) $\hspace{1.03 in}$

Comment: It's not clear to me why this isn't equivalent to VBB. It seems your goal is to make the obfuscator produce something that "acts as if" the evaluator has oracle access to the circuit.

Since we know VBB is impossible, do you have any example or property that separates "better obfuscation" from VBB (even intuitively)?

Comment: For instance, like VBB, your definition would appear to allow ("full") obfuscation of cryptographic functions (since loosely, $A^{PRF_{K_1}}(1^\lambda) \stackrel{c}{\approx} A^{PRF_{K_2}}(1^\lambda)$). This stands in contrast to impossibility results related to superpolynomial pseudoentropy circuit families, e.g. http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/665.pdf

Comment: The property is "computational security": the impossibility proof for VBB uses encryption that is only computationally secure, which may allow $\mathcal{B}$ to distinguish the two cases using only black-box access. $\:$ Similarly, I imagine that most useful-on-their-own cryptographic functions can heuristically be expected to "be trivial" to adversaries like $\mathcal{B}$. $\:$ (I think the main exceptions would be those that $\mathcal{B}$ can't distinguish from being constant, such as verifications algorithms and some decryption algorithms.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Have you seen virtual grey-box obfuscation? http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/414.pdf (Also, you might check if Proposition 3.1 on page 7 answers your original question.)

Comment: I hadn't seen it, and I think their definition is stronger than mine. $\:$ (Proposition 3.1 doesn't answer my question, since the proposition is for when there is no restriction on the number of queries.) $\;\;$

Comment: Alright- it seems that if all circuits in $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$ compute the same function, we recover a definition equivalent to indistinguishability obfuscation. So, the interesting case is when the (obfuscated) circuits being compared have a differing input ($\exists x.\; C_{\mathcal{F}_0}(x) \ne C_{\mathcal{F}_1}(x)$). When this differing input is easy to find, the circuits are distinguishable via black-box access. Since are considering unbounded-time simulation, the differing input must be statistically hard to find. This seems to lead here: http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/668

Comment: FWIW, I think it might be clarifying to re-write the 'better obfuscator' in terms of a single circuit family (with two circuits sampled from the family). For instance, as-written, there is the odd consequence that nothing is necessarily guaranteed about the indistinguishability of the obfuscations of two circuits both drawn from $\mathcal{F}_0$.

Comment: Do you mean a family of _pairs_ of circuits? $\:$ If I changed it to two independent samples from the same family then the differences would both be identically zero. $\;\;\;$

Comment: In every instance in the literature that I'm aware, an obfuscator $\mathcal{O}$ is defined w.r.t. a single collection of circuits $\mathcal{C}$ and the security property is defined w.r.t. indistinguishability of $\mathcal{O}(C_1)$ vs. $\mathcal{O}(C_2)$ for $C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{C}$.

E.g. let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of circuits $C_{y, z}$ where $C_{y, z}(x)=z$ if $x=y$ and $\bot$ otherwise. Since any distinct $C_{y_1, z_1}, C_{y_2, z_2} \in\mathcal{C}$ are statistically indistinguishable via black-box queries, we would want $\mathcal{O}(C_{y_1, z_1})\approx\mathcal{O}(C_{y_2, z_2})$.

Comment: (Alternatively- I'm wondering if you're attempting to capture something not found in the usual definitions involving one circuit collection, which I'm missing.)

Comment: For all $\:y_1,z_1,y_2,z_2\:$, $\:$ if $\: \langle y_1,z_1\rangle \neq \langle y_2,z_2\rangle \:$ then $C_{y_1,z_1}$ can be black-box distinguished from $C_{y_2,z_2}$ by just querying $y_1$. $\;\;\;$ Thus, I don't understand exactly what the hypothesis on the circuit family $\mathcal{C}$ would need to be. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, but $y_1$ is hard to find given only black-box oracle access to the functionality but not access to the circuit description itself. (I.e. if you burn away your poly-many queries seeing only $\bot$, you learn nothing.) By letting the $y_i$ be drawn uniformly over, say, $\{0,1\}^\lambda$, there is a negl ($2^{-\lambda}$) probability (over the random choice of $y_1$) of finding $y_1$ on any given query.

Comment: I guess to make this make complete sense, you can let a challenger specify $z_1, z_2$, and have $y_1, y_2$ drawn uniformly. For $b\stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow}\{1,2\}$, the adversary is given $(\mathcal{O}(C_{y_b, z_b}), z_1, z_2)$, outputs $b'$, and wins if $b' = b$. (...or you can just fix $z_1 = b, z_2 = 1-b$; it doesn't seem to matter.)

Comment: In that case, I guess I'm trying to capture that the definition does not have to be so complicated. $\:$

Comment: Yeah, I think the way you wrote it helps intuition -- it's still a little unclear to me exactly what it's (un)equivalent to and why though. Some of that is due to the fact that the relations between different notions of obfuscation are still relatively unexplored.

Comment: Honestly, my best guess is that this falls somewhere in between the current definition of iO and diO. It seems to reduce to iO in the same-function case, and it seems a little less powerful than diO, because diO allows some type of "computationally hidden" differing input, whereas in your definition, the unbounded-time simulator would find these given black-box access and so there is no guarantee of indistinguishability of obfuscation in this case.